# location is null - is it the same behavior in real device?

Tags: android, location

Hey guys as far as i don't have real android phone I wanted to ask this question.
in my MapActivity which is extended from LocationListener, the onCreate method initializes "location" element as following :

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

When I start my app, the location is always null until I send points from DDMS.
I wanted to know, in real device what would be the behavior?

Comment: You should really get a "real" Android phone to test on. Does the simulator have an accelerometer in it? (no) Does the simulator have GPS? (no)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getLastKnownLocation() only gets the location last returned by the GPS. If the gps has never gotten a location fix, it will be null. You can't count on this method returning a value at all, and if it does it might be extremely out of date.

If you want to get the actual location, you need to set up a locationlistener.

Comment: yes exactly ,  thats why i implemented locationlistener, but my question is, for the very first time when user starts the app, does location listener start?

Comment: I mean does it call its onlocationchanged() method after onCreate()?

Comment: There is no guarantee when/if onlocationchanged is called. getLastKnownLocation has nothing to do with getting a location from a locationlistener though.