# LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation() returns null, and onLocationChanged never gets called

Tags: android, android-mapview, locationmanager, android-location

This code is used on the onCreate block in my MapActivity

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Por favor, habilita el GPS antes de usar esta opción",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        doYourMapMagicBaby(loc);
```

No matter what, loc always returns null. Anyway, when I register for updates on the GPS, the logcat logs my position correctly.

```
08-24 09:21:18.479: D/libloc(260): Latitude:  40.4399979 (intermediate)
08-24 09:21:57.500: D/libloc(260): Longitude: -3.6700022
```

So I thought I could implement what I want to do via the onLocationChanged() method. No luck either.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        System.out.println("La localizacion es: (lon: "
                + location.getLongitude() + ", lat: "
                + location.getLatitude() + ")");
        doYourMapMagicBaby(location);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("La location es nula");
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: System out won't get you anywhere. Use the android Log class.

Comment: I'm just debugging. System.out.println actually prints in the Log. I will remove them when I'm done.

Comment: still. the android Log class is much more helpful

Comment: Are you sure that location was provided by the GPS? Why don't you check the provider as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out whether, provider is currently enabled because If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

Comment: that's, like, the 3rd line of the question... (Although you should return after finish() because the rest of your treatment is still executed)

Comment: Also, the logcat is printing my location, so the GPS certainly has my location.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166317/why-does-the-locationmanager-does-not-have-a-lastknown-location?lq=1